# textbox.Text using index array in c#

Tags: c#

example:

```
textbox1.Text[0]="a";
textbox1.Text[1]="s";
```

so,the text appear in textbox1 is "as"

is there a way to do that?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
textbox1.Text="a";
```

And than, to add more characters to that string use

```
textbox1.Text +="s";
```

Comment: @AndrejBratoz that's right. My bad. Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

No, strings are *immutable*. You can't manipulate strings like that, you need to create a new string and assign it to your `Text`  property. You can assign it directly:

```
textBox1.Text="as";
```

Or you can use a `StringBuilder`:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("a");
builder.Append("s");
textBox1.Text = builder.ToString();
```